# Generated helper functions in a seperate file when transform javascript with babeljs

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Compiling a single javascript (a ES2015 Class) file with babeljs gives me the transformed file like

```
'use strict';

var _createClass = function () { ...

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { ...

The transformed content ...
```

Is there an option to write the generated helper functions ( `_createClass` etc.) in a seperate file?

Comment: Yes it's in the docs

Comment: Where? Link? Thanks!